# Upgrading to debian 11 (from debian 10) not add the kernel in /boot/ (Dedibox Server)

Tags: debian, kernel, upgrade, grub

I have make upgrade on my server and reboot the server to use the last kernel, but after reboot, the server just use the old kernel (4.19.0-16-amd64).

In `/boot/`, I just seen files for kernel `4.19.0-16-amd64`. If I do `apt install linux-image-amd64` the result is `linux-image-amd64 is already the newest version (5.10.46-4)` but this kernel version is not available in `/boot/`, so `update-grub` do nothing.

What can be wrong on my serveur ?

If I do `ls -l` on `/`, I can seen this two line:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    27 Aug 18 16:22 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-8-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    28 Aug 17 13:38 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-17-amd64
```

But this two kernel not exist in `/boot/` folder.

FYI : my server use Raid5 also for `/boot/` partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reply to myself after find a solution.

I do `apt install --reinstall linux-image-5.10.0-8-amd64` and after that the new kernel is correctly available in `/boot` folder.

The command `update-grub` give good result.